# Calls between 2 APIs on the same Kubernetes cluster

Tags: api, kubernetes

I have two Api's on the same cluster and when I run the get services I get the following.

```
dh-service       ClusterIP   10.233.48.45    <none>        15012/TCP           70d
api-service      ClusterIP   10.233.54.208   <none>        15012/TCP
```

Now I want to make a Api call from one API to the other, When I do it using the Ingress address for the two Images I get 404 Not Found.

What address should I use for my post calls? Will the cluster ip work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to make a Api call from one API to the other

If they are in the same namespace and you use http, you can use:

```
http://dh-service
http://api-service
```

to access them.

If e.g. the `api-service` is located in a different namespace e.g. `blue-namespace` you can access it with:

```
http://api-service.blue-namespace
```

See more on [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Comment: is there anyway to check if they are in the same namespace?

Comment: the service must always know the "DNS name" to access another service. If you mean to check when developing, you can check with: `kubectl get services -n <your_namespace>`.

Comment: The DNS address did not work. I get the following response:
 "An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set."

Comment: You were right Jonas  i made a mistake in my code.